# ¿Cómo saber si el número es binario o no cuando lo ingresa en un Texbox?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buenas tengo este codigo en c# donde si se ingresa un  numero en binario debe de retornar un MessageBox.Show("El numero es binario"); pero no logro que evalue si es binario intente con un foreach para que recorra el texbox pero no logro que evalue si es binario o no

```
foreach (var item in texbox.Text)
        {
            if(item =='1'&& item == '0')
            {
                MessageBox.Show("falso");
            }
        }
```

Comment: pregunta, cómo piensas distinguir entre 10 y 2? porque si está en binario en el primer caso es 2 en decimal y si no lo está es 10 en decimal

Comment: Podemos asumir que la comprobación a realizar es simplemente que la entrada dada pueda pasar por un número binario (que sea *parseable* en base 2)

Comment: Deberias  haber ampliado tu información... ya que segun lo que quieras conseguir el for each seria innecesario... por ejemplo si tu quieres  que un usuario introduzca un numero  , y al persionar un boton le diga si es  binario o no... el for each seria innecesario , ya que con colocar el condicional que te hemos comentado varias personas  dentro de un evento onclick del boton ya te funcionaria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ampliando la respuesta de iqanansoft, deberías sacar el MessageBox fuera del bucle y sustituirlo por una variable, invirtiendo además el condicional. Además, a mí me gusta usar el Equals directamente sobre el string (o el char, como en este caso). Algo como así:

```
var result = "El número es binario";
foreach (var item in texbox.Text)
{
    if(Not item.Equals('1') AndAlso Not item.Equals('0'))
    {
        result = "El número no es binario";
        break;
    }
}
MessageBox.Show(result);
```

Añado una explicación de por qué falla tu código:

- Tal y como te han dicho, es conveniente comparar las cadenas de texto o caracteres con el método Equals
- Aún usando el método Equals, si comparas un 'item' con el caracter '1' y además con el caracter '0' es imposible que los dos a la vez sean True. Al usar el && (AND) para combinarlos, esa condición nunca se cumplirá
- Si por lo que sea esa condición se pudiera dar, mostraría un messagebox por cada carácter inválido que encontrara, lo cual no tiene sentido. De ahí el break, para que termine la ejecución una vez se encuentre un carácter inválido

Comment: El usuario esta esperando código en C#.

Comment: @David_helo Esta respuesta es mejor que código: explica una solución, en lugar de darla sin más

Answer (score 1):

El problema no radica en el operador de comparación, sino, en el operador lógico `AND`.

Es decir, esta condición:

```cs
if(item =='1'&& item == '0')
```

Nunca se cumplirá, debido a que, la variable `item` tendrá únicamente un valor (que en realidad es el código ASCII de X caracter), por lo tanto, no es posible que la variable pueda tener el `'1'` y `'0'` almacenado al mismo tiempo. Por esa razón, cuando `item` tenga guardado el caracter `'1'`, la restricción `item == '0'` dará `false`, ocasionando que toda la condición dé como resultado `false` y esto hace que en ningún momento el `if` se ejecute.

Una solución sencilla es cambiar el operador `AND` por el `OR`:

```cs
if(item == '1' || item == '0')
    MessageBox.Show("Hay un número binario!!");
```

De este modo, establecemos dos posibles valores que puede tener la variable `item`.

El problema de este código que en cada iteración estará mostrando al usuario un mensaje y no debería ser así.

Entonces para solucionar este inconveniente, podemos crear una variable de tipo `bool` en la cual nos diga si el número es binario o no.

Código en C#:

```cs
bool esBinario = true;
foreach (var item in textbox.Text)
{
      //Si la variable item no tiene el valor de '1' o de '0' es porque no es binario..
      if (item != '1' && item != '0')
      {
          MessageBox.Show("El numero no es binario.");
          esBinario = false;
          break;
      }
}
//Si la variable tiene almacenado un true, es porque el numero es binario.
//La condición es equivalente a esBinario == true
if(esBinario)
   MessageBox.Show("El numero es binario.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Aunque ya te han dado buenas soluciones, para estos casos puedes usar una expresión regular como la siguiente:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var result = Regex.IsMatch(texbox.Text?.Trim(), "^[01]+$") ? "El número es binario" : "El número no es binario";
MessageBox.Show(result);
```